# Need help in a MS SQL DB design

Tags: sql-server, database

Hi I have 2 type of data entry which needs to be stored in db so it can be used for calculations later. Each entry has a unique id for it. The data entry are -

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

So I have to save this data in DB. With my understanding I thought of the following -

1. Create 3 tables - Common, Entry1 and Entry2(multiple tables with unique id as name)
2. The Common table will have a unique entry of each data and which table refer to for the value (Entry1/Entry2).

The Entry1 data is a single line so it can be inserted. But the Entry2 data will require a complete table because of its structure. So whenever we add a type 2 entry then a new table has to be created, which will create a lot of tables.

Or I could save the type2 values in another database and fetch the values from there. So please suggest me a way which is better than this.

Comment: MySQL and ms sql server are two different products. Pls use the relevant product tags only.

Comment: @Shadow : Thanks will take care next time... :D

Comment: You shouldn't structure your database based on *data entry*. You should structure your data based on the actual nature of the data. Ideally, all values of the same "type" should be appearing in a single column of one table. Unfortunately, your samples are too abstract to give much in the way of recommendations. Importantly, though, don't treat *tables* in the same way as you might *spreadsheets*. With tables, columns and rows are fundamentally different.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I need to store values from both the excel format inside db. So later on I can fetch the data and use it for specific calculations. I will be needing the 2 types of data for calculation for a specific month and there will be a lot of data for different month. So how can I handle that.

Comment: Like I say - it's too abstract here. But for instance, I would commonly expect your second sample to be *stored* as a table with 30 rows, 3 columns. The first row would be `('20170501','A',12)`. The second row would be `('20170501','B',23)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have 2 entry types with identical structure, but one containing a single row and one containing many.

In this case, I would suggest a single table containing the data for all entries, wtih a second table grouping them together. Even if your input contains a single row, it should still gain an EntryID.  Perhaps something like the below:

[image: Entity Diagram]